# What are the default repositories that SBT uses?

Tags: scala, sbt

I can provide a `~/.sbt/repositories` file to override the repositories that SBT uses for resolving dependencies. When the file is present the default repositories aren't used.

What are the default repositories in SBT (0.13)? I want to add them to my repositories file so I can resolve dependencies inside and outside the network without having to change/move the file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to *add* to the default repositories (instead of replacing them), I think the easiest would be to create an `.sbt` file inside `~/sbt/0.13/`, e.g. `~/sbt/0.13/my-resolvers.sbt`:

```
resolvers += "Oracle Repository" at "http://download.oracle.com/maven"
```

Otherwise, you can find out in the sbt console via `show externalResolvers`. The entries are stored in [sbt.boot.properties](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.13.17/launch/src/main/input_resources/sbt/sbt.boot.properties), which ends up as the `sbt/sbt.boot.properties` file in the launcher jar (for example `~/.sbt/launchers/0.13.17/sbt-launch.jar`):

```
[repositories]
  local
  local-preloaded-ivy: file:///${sbt.preloaded-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/preloaded/}, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  local-preloaded: file:///${sbt.preloaded-${sbt.global.base-${user.home}/.sbt}/preloaded/}
  maven-central
  typesafe-ivy-releases: https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
sbt-ivy-snapshots: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext], bootOnly
```