# SBT: is there a way to print the list of resolvers?

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

I have a big project with many plugins. I think some of the resolvers are been added by some of the plugins. Is there a way to see what is there in the list of resolvers? (and how there are ordered?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
>sbt
>show fullResolvers //list all *resolvers* in project,
>show resolvers //list added *resolvers*
```

and you also can use `inspect` to replace `show`, like: `inspect resolvers`.

The order is in a `ArrayBuffer`. if you want to change the order, maybe this article is helpful:

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you check also the *default* resolvers used by `sbt`.

They can be found in `sbt.boot.properties` file, see details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35009026/330067