# What repo is SBT using?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to figure out what repo SBT is using?

In my ~/.sbt directory:

```
0.13        1.0     boot        launchers   preloaded
```

In my build.sbt

```
name := "TestLab1"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0"
```

Comment: *Not* a duplicate of ['What are the default repositories that sbt uses?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008617/what-are-the-default-repositories-that-sbt-uses/35009026), because the linked question is an XY-problem, and the answer provides a solution for X.

Comment: What exactly did you attempt to "figure out what repo SBT is using"? Doesn't it write the full url of every repo that it uses when it downloads stuff? Was [the documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html) of no use at all? I don't see how the the provided pieces of `build.sbt` are supposed to help, they don't modify resolvers in any way.

Answer (score 0):

take a look in your build.properties in the project folder.

there is a sbt.version property set.

check https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Basic-Def.html#Specifying+the+sbt+version

I hope that could answer your question.